# Oracle Table Dropped But Still Exists

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

I have dropped some tables but when I'm trying to create tables again getting error "ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object". Please help.

1. No data is available in RECYCLEBIN.
2. And also table name is not available in all_objects.

#oracle19c

Comment: That is odd.  Did you also lookin DBA_OBJECTS?

Comment: Please, demonstrate it by copy/pasting your SQL*Plus session.